# Create an image wherever someone taps- .append combined with pageX and Pagey

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm trying to create an interaction on smartpphones (iOS and Android) that creates an image wherever someone has tapped on the screen. Using jQuery Mobile this is the js I have right now:

```
$('#container1').bind('tap', function(e) {
 $('img').css({
  position: 'absolute',
  left:  e.pageX,
  top: e.pageY
 });
 $("#container1").append('<img  src="image.png" />');
});
```

However this creates an instance of the image and keeps stacking them wherever the user taps. How do I combine the two chunks of code to create unique instances of the same image wherever someone taps with unique X and Y positions? Thanks!

Comment: Of course it stacks all images in the current position, because you are using the very basic selector "img", which means all images currently in the document. You could just set the styles on the image directly, by giving it a `style` attribute directly in the HTML code you use to append it.

Comment: Right so I would do something like: 

$("#container1").append('<img  src="image.png" style="position:absolute;top:pageY;left:pageX;" />');

Comment: @user1922019 I added an answer. You forgot `px` after pageX and pageY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code

```
$('img').css({
    position: 'absolute',
    left:  e.pageX,
    top: e.pageY
});
```

Is changing the position of **all** `img` tags on the page. You may want to manually set the style attribute of the image you add:

```
$('#container1').bind('tap', function(e) {
    var image = '<img src="image.png" style="position:absolute;left:' + e.pageX +
        ';top:' + e.pageY';" />';
    $("#container1").append(image);
}
```

Comment: That didn't seem to work, but I may have done something wrong:
`<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 
 $('#container1').bind('tap', function(e) {
    var image = '<img src="image.png" style="position:absolute;left:' + e.pageX +
        ';top:' + e.pageY';" />';
    $("#container1").append(image);
 });
  
});
</script>`

Comment: @Alejo it seems like something with style="position:absolute;left:' + e.pageX +';top:' + e.pageY'; is causing it to break. When I remove that it works. But it doesn't give each img a unique position

Comment: That worked! Can you add it as an answer so I can check it off! I's also love to know why that works if you have the time